# How to install single package from metapackage through a command line in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, installer

I’ve got a metapackage file `program.mpkg`. I’m using Mac OS X `installer` command to install `.pkg` and `.mpkg` files via command line usually like so:

```
$ sudo installer -pkg program.mpkg -tgt  /
```

The metapackage content:

```
$ installer -pkg program.mpkg -pkginfo`
program
prog-command-line
GUI-front-end
```

By default all these three packages inside program.mpkg are going to be installed, but I need to install a single package `GUI-front-end` from this metapackage using a command line only.

**EDIT:**

I've used the `-config` option:

```
$ installer -pkg ~/Documents/program.pkg -target / -config > /tmp/prog.plist
```

and got a **prog.plist**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Package</key>
    <string>program.mpkg</string>
    <key>Target</key>
    <string>/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

How should I change it in order to install only `GUI-front-end` package instead of all three available packages from the .mpkg?

**EDIT:**

I've tried to unflatten metapackage with:

```
$ pkgutil --expand /Volumes/Prog/program.mpkg ~/Desktop/folder
```

But getting:

```
Could not open package for expansion: /Volumes/Prog/program.mpkg
```

All files and folders exist... Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming that your .mpkg is flatten then use pkgutil to unflatten the m package. Then install the .pkg that you want to install. YMMV

Comment: Thanx! But could you please be more detailed how to unflatten the m package with pkgutil?

Comment: I've edited my question... please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution was extremely easy - the .mpkg file looks like a simple driectory when you look at it throug the shell, so just `cd` inside find your .pkg and do with it whatever you want... for example:

```
cp metapkg.mpkg/some.pkg /tmp/some.pkg
sudo installer -pkg /tmp/some.pkg -tgt /
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-config` option of installer.  Here's what the man page says about this option

> **-config**
>
> Formats the command line installation arguments for later use.  The output is sent to stdout, but can be redirected to a file to
>   create a configuration file.  When specifying this option, an
>   installation is not actually performed.  This configuration file can
>   be supplied as the argument to the -file parameter instead of typing a
>   long series of installation arguments.  The config file can be used to
>   perform multiple identical installs.  You can create a config file as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> installer -pkg ~/Documents/Foo.pkg -target / -config > /tmp/configfile.plist
> ```

If you follow the example, you can then edit the resulting `.plist` file and then use `-file /tmp/configfile.plist` to actually run the installation with the options you've specified. This approach is common for us who create repeatable installations for corporate clients. But know in advance that not all installers are written the same. You may need to test your install on a test VM or machine to make sure you're getting just the options you want.  GL

Comment: Thanx for reply, I've updated my question.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? I'm not familiar with `pkgutil`

Comment: Yes I did - read my first EDIT please